# App crash Apple reject OS 11.3.1

Tags: ios

I have test and submit my app to Apple Store but Apple reject and response my app crash on launch. I have test my app on many model iPhone and iPad it's working normal, Have anyone can tell me why? Crash log Apple send to me:

```
Incident Identifier: 1CABA1F8-5294-4432-AA91-7C4F680C30ED
CrashReporter Key:   5482aa07df93439045718ce254e6392cce5ade36
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             bfwsqy [1829]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F359F454-6131-4447-ABC3-25F759E25C05/***.app/***
Identifier:          com.***
Version:             2.0.7.3 (2.0.7)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.*** [756]


Date/Time:           2018-05-08 09:25:53.3872 +0800
Launch Time:         2018-05-08 09:24:54.2355 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)
Baseband Version:    6.55.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1825cad8c 0x1817845ec 0x182563750 0x1825508ac 0x100acde90 0x18c1a6ee0 0x18c254e98 0x18c254354 0x18c253c90 0x18c253720 0x18c247424 0x18c19f770 0x18674125c 0x1867453ec 0x1866b1aa0 0x1866d95d0 0x1866da450 0x182572910 0x182570238 0x182570884 0x182490da8 0x184473020 0x18c47178c 0x100a9fd9c 0x181f21fc0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001820512ec 0x18202f000 + 140012
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f2288 0x1821ef000 + 12936
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181fbfd0c 0x181f5d000 + 404748
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018175a2c8 0x181759000 + 4808
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018175a470 0x181759000 + 5232
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001817848d4 0x18177c000 + 35028
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018177437c 0x181759000 + 111484
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181773f78 0x181759000 + 110456
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001817847ac 0x18177c000 + 34732
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182490e18 0x182485000 + 48664
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184473020 0x184468000 + 45088
11  UIKit                           0x000000018c47178c 0x18c154000 + 3266444
12  bfwsqy                          0x0000000100a9fd9c 0x1009f0000 + 720284
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000181f21fc0 0x181f21000 + 4032

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fe08 0x18202f000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fc80 0x18202f000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182572e40 0x182485000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182570908 0x182485000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182490da8 0x182485000 + 48552
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182f05674 0x182efd000 + 34420
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182f0551c 0x182efd000 + 34076
7   UIKit                           0x000000018c1567e4 0x18c154000 + 10212
8   Foundation                      0x0000000183015efc 0x182efd000 + 1150716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182051610 0x18202f000 + 140816
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181f6a12c 0x181f5d000 + 53548
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181fd2ef4 0x181f5d000 + 483060
3   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100ed6aa8 0x1009f0000 + 5139112
4   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100ed46d4 0x1009f0000 + 5129940
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fe08 0x18202f000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fc80 0x18202f000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182572e40 0x182485000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182570908 0x182485000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182490da8 0x182485000 + 48552
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182d9e4b0 0x182b4e000 + 2426032
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183015efc 0x182efd000 + 1150716
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001820510f4 0x18202f000 + 139508
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f3c90 0x1821ef000 + 19600
2   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100ba2a30 0x1009f0000 + 1780272
3   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100ba2f08 0x1009f0000 + 1781512
4   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100ba18b4 0x1009f0000 + 1775796
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182051538 0x18202f000 + 140600
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018257b378 0x182485000 + 1008504
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c01285c0.events
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fe5c 0x18202f000 + 3676
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ebf0b0 0x181ebb000 + 16560
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ebf924 0x181ebb000 + 18724
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d3c888 0x188d39000 + 14472
4   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d4243c 0x188d39000 + 37948
5   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d4211c 0x188d39000 + 37148
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d98928 0x188d39000 + 391464
7   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d94988 0x188d39000 + 375176
8   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d94850 0x188d39000 + 374864
9   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188d962ac 0x188d39000 + 381612
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018222b220 0x182226000 + 21024
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000182228bb4 0x182226000 + 11188
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ebcbb4 0x181ebb000 + 7092
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ed34c4 0x181ebb000 + 99524
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ec68f0 0x181ebb000 + 47344
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ed3f70 0x181ebb000 + 102256
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ec68f0 0x181ebb000 + 47344
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ec7380 0x181ebb000 + 50048
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ec68f0 0x181ebb000 + 47344
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ec7380 0x181ebb000 + 50048
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ec7d4c 0x181ebb000 + 52556
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181ed011c 0x181ebb000 + 86300
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efe70 0x1821ef000 + 3696
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb08 0x1821ef000 + 2824

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182051d84 0x18202f000 + 142724
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efeb4 0x1821ef000 + 3764
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb08 0x1821ef000 + 2824

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb04 0x1821ef000 + 2820

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb04 0x1821ef000 + 2820

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fe08 0x18202f000 + 3592
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018202fc80 0x18202f000 + 3200
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182572e40 0x182485000 + 974400
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182570908 0x182485000 + 964872
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182490da8 0x182485000 + 48552
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824e0b28 0x182485000 + 375592
6   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100a92e98 0x1009f0000 + 667288
7   Foundation                      0x0000000183015efc 0x182efd000 + 1150716
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182051610 0x18202f000 + 140816
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181f6a12c 0x181f5d000 + 53548
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181f6a04c 0x181f5d000 + 53324
3   bfwsqy                          0x0000000100c61170 0x1009f0000 + 2560368
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1220 0x1821ef000 + 8736
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821f1110 0x1821ef000 + 8464
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001821efb10 0x1821ef000 + 2832

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001c42e1b37
    x4: 0x0000000181779abd   x5: 0x000000016f40f3e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000001821f2110  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000300  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b443ab40  x21: 0x000000016f40f3e0  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b443ac20
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000001c0015420  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x000000016f40fb28   fp: 0x000000016f40f340   lr: 0x00000001821f2288
    sp: 0x000000016f40f310   pc: 0x00000001820512ec cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1009f0000 - 0x101073fff bfwsqy arm64  <b299c2116b9330aebd462a1a5f0a0d10> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F359F454-6131-4447-ABC3-25F759E25C05/bfwsqy.app/bfwsqy
```

Now i can't test with iOS 11.3.1 because Apple not allow signing in iOS version 11.3.1 or downgrade version to 11.3.1. Please help me.

Comment: Xcode won't symbolicate it for you so you could see what exactly the call in thread 0 your code does is? Without that it's quite hard to figure out where exactly it's crashing.

Comment: Your app crashed because `abort()` was called. From the stack trace it appears it was inside iOS code somewhere, but is almost certainly because of something your app has done (or not done correctly). Have you tested a TestFlight build?  It seems that your app was potentially running network and location services code in the background.  Symbolicate your crash log and see if it helps